# How to run Nx executor function with Node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, monorepo, nx-monorepo

Is it possible to run a custom **Nx** executor function after building the app image?

Here it's the approach that I follow

```
"migrate-up": {
      "executor": "@nx-mongo-migrate/mongo-migrate:up",
      "options": {
        "migrationDirectory": "migrations"
      }
    }
}
```

By using the package from my apps directory, I can easily run this command by `nx run my-app:migrate-up` and this works well locally. My question is, is it possible to run it after building the image of my **my-app**? Hence, I can run it directly with **node**?

Answer (score 0):

Sure! If you already have your `/node_modules` created, you can run nx directly from its `node_modules` directory:

```
node node_modules/nx/bin/nx.js my-app:migrate-up
```

However, you can install `nx` globally in your machine and continue using nx:

```
yarn global add nx && nx run my-app:migrate-up
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think that I can follow this approach with Kubernetes Init containers (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)?

Comment: @BySpecops. Of course (if you already installed node).